# Lazy Load for multiple entities at a time

Tags: c#, database, lazy

We have a system with a non standard database solution. All trips to the DB are rather expensive. We cannot use entity framework.

Currently our lazy loading is on an entity by entity basis. So if I have a `Customer` and access their `Orders` object it only loads the `Orders` for that customer.

Something like so

```
//DAL
public List<Entities.Customer> GetCustomersByIds(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var customers = db.GetCustomersByIds(ids);
    foreach(var customer in customers)
    {
        customer.Orders = new ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>>(() => 
            db.GetOrdersByCustomerId(c.Id));
    }
    return customers;
}
```

ResetLazy taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255398/102526

Ideally if we had a collection of `Customers` and accessed an `Orders` collection on one of the customers it would load all the `Orders` for all the `Customers`. (If not in a collection it would just load it's own orders)

```
//DAL
public List<Entities.Customer> GetCustomersByIds(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var customers = db.GetCustomersByIds(ids);
    foreach(var customer in customers)
    {
        customer.Orders = new ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>>(() => 
            GetOrdersByCustomersLazy(customers, customer.Id));
    }
    return customers;
}

protected List<Entities.Order> GetOrdersByCustomersLazy(
    List<Entities.Customer> customers, 
    int customerId)
{
    var orders = db.GetOrdersByCustomerIds(
        customers.Select(customer => customer.Id).AsEnumerable());
    foreach(var customer in customers)
    {
        customer.Orders = new ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>>(() => {
            customer.Orders = new ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>>(() => 
                GetOrdersByCustomersLazy(customers, customer.Id));
            return orders.Where(order => order.CustomerId == customer.Id).ToList();
        });
    }
    return customers.FirstOrDefault(customer => customer.Id == customerId).Orders.Value;
}
```

This seems to work well, but it is too complex and not generic.

Answer (score 2):

You code seems to not doing what it is supposed to do.

Assume the following implementation (using the [`ResetLazy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255398/2655508))

**Customer and Order**

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>> Orders {get;set;}
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Simulated database**

```
public class TheDatabase
{
    public TheDatabase()
    {
        customers.Add(new Entities.Customer { Id = 1 });
        orders.Add(new Entities.Order { Id = 1, CustomerId = 1 });
        orders.Add(new Entities.Order { Id = 2, CustomerId = 1 });
        orders.Add(new Entities.Order { Id = 3, CustomerId = 1 });

        customers.Add(new Entities.Customer { Id = 2 });

        customers.Add(new Entities.Customer { Id = 3 });
        orders.Add(new Entities.Order { Id = 4, CustomerId = 3 });
        orders.Add(new Entities.Order { Id = 5, CustomerId = 3 });
    }
    private List<Entities.Customer> customers = new List<Entities.Customer>();
    private List<Entities.Order> orders = new List<Entities.Order>();
    public List<Entities.Customer> GetCustomersByIds(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        return customers.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Entities.Order> GetOrdersByCustomerIds(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        return orders.Where(c => IsContained(c.CustomerId, ids));
    }
    private bool IsContained(int id, IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        foreach (int currentId in ids)
        {
            if (id == currentId) { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the class containing your methods

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        IEnumerable<int> ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        List<Entities.Customer> customers = p.GetCustomersByIds(ids);

        int customerId = 1;
        List<Entities.Order> orders = new List<Entities.Order>(customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId).First().Orders.Value);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(orders[0].CustomerId == customerId);
    }

    TheDatabase db;
    private Program()
    {
        db = new TheDatabase();
    }

    public List<Entities.Customer> GetCustomersByIds(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        var customers = db.GetCustomersByIds(ids);
        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            customer.Orders = new ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>>(() =>
                GetOrdersByCustomersLazy(customers, customer.Id));
        }
        return customers;
    }

    protected List<Entities.Order> GetOrdersByCustomersLazy(
        List<Entities.Customer> customers,
        int customerId)
    {
        var orders = db.GetOrdersByCustomerIds(
            customers.Select(customer => customer.Id).AsEnumerable());
        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            customer.Orders = new ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>>(() =>
            {
                customer.Orders = new ResetLazy<List<Entities.Order>>(() =>
                    GetOrdersByCustomersLazy(customers, customer.Id));
                return orders.Where(order => order.CustomerId == customer.Id).ToList();
            });
        }
        return customers.FirstOrDefault(customer => customer.Id == customerId).Orders.Value;
    }
}
```

The `Debug.Assert()` method signals the wrong id.

**Fixing**

By adding a setter to `ResetLazy.Value` like

```
set
{

    if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.None)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            this.box = new Box(value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.box = new Box(value);
    }
}
```

and changing the `GetOrdersByCustomersLazy()` method to

```
protected List<Entities.Order> GetOrdersByCustomersLazy(
    List<Entities.Customer> customers,
    int customerId)
{
    var orders = db.GetOrdersByCustomerIds(
        customers.Select(customer => customer.Id).AsEnumerable());
    foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        customer.Orders.Value = orders.Where(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id).ToList();
    }
    return customers.FirstOrDefault(customer => customer.Id == customerId).Orders.Value;
}
```

The following runs as expected

```
Program p = new Program();
IEnumerable<int> ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Entities.Customer> customers = p.GetCustomersByIds(ids);

int customerId = 1;
List<Entities.Order> orders = new List<Entities.Order>(customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId).First().Orders.Value);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(orders.Count==3 && orders[0].CustomerId == customerId);

customerId = 2;
orders = new List<Entities.Order>(customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId).First().Orders.Value);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(orders.Count==0);

customerId = 3;
orders = new List<Entities.Order>(customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId).First().Orders.Value);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(orders.Count == 2 && orders[0].CustomerId == customerId);
```

---

You shouldn't shorten names of variables. The advantage of typing less is reduced by the lack of readability.

---

A call to the linq `Select()` method returns an `IEnumerable` so a call to `AsEnumerable()` is not needed.